# Openvswitch change header field

Tags: openvswitch

I want add new field openvswitch pattern. My openvswitch (/var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitch.log) looking like follow ;

```
2017-05-21T18:00:06.572Z|00105|rconn|WARN|s2<->tcp:192.168.29.87:6633: connection failed (Network is unreachable)
2017-05-21T18:00:07.572Z|00106|stream_tcp|ERR|tcp:192.168.29.87:6633: connect: Network is unreachable
2017-05-21T18:00:07.572Z|00107|rconn|WARN|s1<->tcp:192.168.29.87:6633: connection failed (Network is unreachable)
2017-05-21T18:00:07.572Z|00108|stream_tcp|ERR|tcp:192.168.29.87:6633: connect: Network is unreachable
2017-05-21T18:00:07.572Z|00109|rconn|WARN|s2<->tcp:192.168.29.87:6633: connection failed (Network is unreachable)
2017-05-21T18:00:08.248Z|00110|bridge|WARN|could not open network device s1-eth2 (No such device)
2017-05-21T18:00:08.257Z|00111|bridge|WARN|could not open network device s1-eth1 (No such device)
```

I want to add switchID  this file. Can I make that? Otherwise  this is impossible.

Have a good day everybody.

Answer (score 0):

what it's your meaning about openvswitch header?

for your log about, the error is about the port is not present,
you must add port to bridge that you make,

example:
the output of `ifconfig` is : `enp3s0` and `enp3s1`
you want to add those port to ovs bridge

```
ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-br ovs-br #add ovs bridge name ovs-br
ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-port ovs-br enp3s0 #add enp3s0 to ovs-br
ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-port ovs-br enp3s1
```

Comment: I just index into  hbase  this log file . This  error  not  important  for me and  I wanted to do change  my  openvswitch pattern  I made  this  `sudo ovs-appctl  vlog/set PATTERN:SYSLOG:ovs|%05N|%c|%T|%p|%A|%B|%E|%P|%r|%t|%m ` with this  line thank you